# how execute COPY statement in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I usually use the `CUSTOM` backup restore but got an error, so I went with the `plain text` option to see if I detect where is the error.

I load it the backup file on pgAdmin / SQL Editor, can create the tables and function but get an error on the load data section.

This is the small table. Where I save what is the current snapshot.

```
CREATE TABLE rt_version (
    traffic_version timestamp without time zone
);


ALTER TABLE traffic.rt_version OWNER TO postgres;

COPY rt_version (traffic_version) FROM stdin;
2016-05-11 14:35:00.095
\.
```

[image]

Comment: You can't use `copy .. from stdin` in pgAdmin: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41039/usage-of-copy-from-stdin-in-postgres

Answer (score 3):

In PgAdmin's main screen's menu, there's a main menu **"Plugins"**, which will likely have a submenu **"PSQL Console"**. That will open a psql connected to the database you have selected, and you can use `COPY FROM STDIN` in it.